# Assign column name based on key in preceding column

Tags: r, list, dataframe, key

I am importing a data set from a csv

the top two lines are key value pairs

| UTC | BSP | AWA | TWA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1. | 2. | 3. | 4. |

Then the data below this has a column containing the value and then the corresponding data. for example

| 1 | 41223 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 045 | 4 | 026 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 41224 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 052 | 4 | 035 |
| 1 | 41225 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 087 | 4 | 040 |
| 1 | 41226 | 2 | 0 | 3 | 023 | 4 | 041 |
| 2 | 0 | 3 | 052 | 4 | 082 |  |  |

I want it to become

| UTC | BSP | AWA | TWA |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 41223 | 0 | 045 | 026 |

I tried putting the key value pairs in a list

```
test <- read.csv("my.csv", 
                  nrows=2, header=FALSE)
key <- as.character(test[1,])
value <- as.numeric(test[2,])

mylist <- list()
for(i in 1:length(key)){
  mylist[key[i]] <- value[i] 
}
```

And then I was trying to match or reference the previous column with the values in the list.  I have not managed to do.

Any help much appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Not clear about the second set of data.  Is it a different dataset.  Can you update with the `dput` of the example so that structure is more clear

Comment: Does the 2nd row of your csv include dots after the numbers? Do the rows from 3 onward really look like that (data is in 2 columns but haphazardly stuck side-by-side)? This may be a rare case where a screenshot would actually help.

Comment: Can you please use `dput` so that we get the structure correctly